# JMX JConsole not showing CMS LastGCInfo

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jmx, jconsole

I was looking at the Garbage Collection Statistics and was wondering why the `LastGCInfo` is empty for `ConcurrentMarkSweep`. Although, I see the `CollectionCount` and `CollectionTime` Info for the same.

[image: Screenshot]

Could someone please help me understand why.

Comment: Is it possible that the CMS has not been called yet ?

Comment: I triggered the GC manually from the jconsole from the 'Perform GC' option in the Memory Tab but i dont see the LastGCInfo updated for CMS.

Comment: Here is the output from -XX:+PrintGCDetails when i trigger GC manually. It looks strange to me since the GCDetails show the CMS Old Generation details but the LastGCInfo in the MBeans tab shows nothing

381882.849: [Full GC (System) 381882.849: [CMS: 923875K->380235K(2752512K), 2.6375400 secs] 1055567K->380235K(3106432K),
 [CMS Perm : 58358K->58058K(65536K)] icms_dc=0 , 2.6378670 secs] [Times: user=2.64 sys=0.00, real=2.64 secs]
381885.493: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 380235K(2752512K)] 380241K(3106432K), 0.0065160 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, r
eal=0.00 secs]

Comment: What about the java versions of jconsole and the target JVM ?